# Do we need separate DB Index for a SQL query containing multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have a query:-

```sql
Select *
from table
where (column1 = 'A' and Column2 = 'B' and Column3 = 'C')
   OR (Column1= 'z' and Column4 = 'X');
```

If I have to create a DB index for this query,

Do we need separate DB index for the first half and second half of the OR condition of the query ?

or

A single DB index would be enough containing all columns present in the query?

Comment: An `INDEX` on `Column1` which `INCLUDE`s every other column in the table (due to the use of `SELECT *`) could be the most useful here, if you wanted to do this in a single `WHERE`, due to the value of `Column1` needing to be either `'A'` or `'z'`.

Comment: Try it and see. If these are always the fixed values you search on then one filtered index on on `column1 = 'A' and Column2 = 'B' and Column3 = 'C'` and another filtered index on `Column1= 'z' and Column4 = 'X'` will help.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The values are dynamic.

Comment: @Larnu The values `A` or `Z` are not static. The values are dynamic.

Comment: But `Column1` presumably is, @AJ. ?

Comment: @Larnu Ya the Columns are always gona be like that in where clause.

Comment: @Larnu so you want to say that just one index is enough on `Column1` including other columns ?

Comment: @Larnu All I know is, it should not look for `Index Scan` . It should look for only `Index Seek`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Create 2 `INDEX`es, one on Columns1-3 and the other on Columns1 & 4, `INCLUDE` all the other columns in the table on both `INDEX`es, and then use a `UNION ALL` query instead.

#### Demonstration

As I mention in the comment, if you wanted to do this in a single query, without a `UNION` (unlike in [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73907902/2029983)) then more likely you would want an `INDEX` on `Column1`, and then `INCLUDE` all the other columns in your table (all, because you use `SELECT *` and so return *all* the columns, even those in referenced in the `WHERE`).

I do think that Tim's solution would likely be better though, especially with a much larger data set, however, that too should have some `INCLUDE`s in it. Without those then either a scan will be performed (which isn't helpful here) or a potentially expensive key lookup.

Here's a little demonstration with a sample table and images of the query plans.

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Column1 char(1),
                            Column2 char(1),
                            Column3 char(1),
                            Column4 char(1),
                            Column5 int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('A','B','C','D',7),
      ('A','B','C','F',9),
      ('A','B','D','Z',1),
      ('D','B','C','X',9),
      ('Z','B','C','X',7),
      ('Z','D','C','X',4),
      ('Z','B','C','Y',9);
GO
```

Create Tim's indexes and test:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1_tim ON dbo.yourTable (Column1, Column2, Column3);
CREATE INDEX idx2_tim ON dbo.yourTable (Column1, Column4);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'A'
  AND Column2 = 'B'
  AND Column3 = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'z'
  AND Column4 = 'X';
GO
```

[image: Query Plan demonstrating 2 table scans]
Notice this have 2 table scans, as there are no `INCLUDE`s (this is not `Column5`'s fault, and I demonstrate this later)

Single `SELECT` with an `INDEX` on `Column1`, but `Column5` excluded from `INCLUDE`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_larnu ON dbo.YourTable (Column1) INCLUDE(Column2, Column3, Column4);
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (Column1 = 'A' AND Column2 = 'B' AND Column3 = 'C')
   OR (Column1= 'z' AND Column4 = 'X');
GO
```

[image: Query Plan demonstrating a table scan]
Note this too has a table scan, due to the ommission of `Column5`. If we add that to the `INCLUDE`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_larnu_fullinc ON dbo.YourTable (Column1) INCLUDE(Column2, Column3, Column4,Column5);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (Column1 = 'A' AND Column2 = 'B' AND Column3 = 'C')
   OR (Column1= 'z' AND Column4 = 'X');
GO
```

[image: Query plan demonstrating a single index scan]
This unfortunately still results in a scan, but of the index this time not the table. For a larger table or for different values of `Column1`, SQL Server *may* make a different decision.

Now let's just add an `INCLUDE` to Tim's indexes:

```sql
--Drop mine so that they definitely aren't used
DROP INDEX idx_larnu_fullinc ON dbo.YourTable; 
DROP INDEX idx_larnu ON dbo.YourTable;
CREATE INDEX idx1_tim_inc ON dbo.yourTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) INCLUDE (Column4,Column5);
CREATE INDEX idx2_tim_inc ON dbo.yourTable (Column1, Column4) INCLUDE (Column2, Column3,Column5);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'A'
  AND Column2 = 'B'
  AND Column3 = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'z'
  AND Column4 = 'X';
GO
```

[image: Query Plan demonstrating 2 seeks]
Hazaar! This is what we want. Also, just to confirm however that `Column5` wasn't causing the scans earlier, let's drop those `INDEX`es and also `Column5`:

```sql
DROP INDEX idx1_tim_inc ON dbo.YourTable;
DROP INDEX idx2_tim_inc ON dbo.YourTable;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN Column5;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'A'
  AND Column2 = 'B'
  AND Column3 = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Column1 = 'z'
  AND Column4 = 'X';
GO
```

[image: Query plan demonstrating 2 scans]
So, there you can see that `Column5` wasn't the cause the scans

```sql
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: I can't thank enough for the explanation.  I created two separate `INDEX`es. with includes and it is using `Index Seek`.

Answer (score 2):

`OR` conditions make indexing tricky.  We can try the following union approach:

```sql
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Column1 = 'A' AND Column2 = 'B' AND Column3 = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Column1 = 'z' AND Column4 = 'X';
```

Then add the following indices to cover the `WHERE` clauses from both halves of the union query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON yourTable (Column1, Column2, Column3);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON yourTable (Column1, Column4);
```

Comment: Might as well use a `UNION ALL` here; it'll be more performant, due to the lack of requiring a sort to check the rows are duplicates, and it's impossible for the 2 `SELECT`s to return the same rows.

Comment: @Larnu: Funny, I started off with union all but was literally thinking you would nail me for choosing that over plain union.  It happened anyway `:-(`

Comment: No, I agree that 2 `UNION`ed queries are likely to be the better option here, even if it requires 2 scans of the table.

Comment: The application from which the query is getting generated cannot use UNION ALL kind of keywords. It can generate only `AND` and `OR`  in between the where condition columns.

Comment: The `INDEX`es may well need an `INCLUDE` on all the other columns in the table, due to the `SELECT *` though, as otherwise it will either not use the index or result in a (potentially expensive) key lookup. We don't know what all those columns are though, but the OP is in a better position to test in the `INCLUDE`s help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you suggesting to create separate indexes ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  All I know is, it should not look for `Index Scan` . It should look for only `Index Seek`.

Comment: @AJ. Yes, I'm clearly suggesting that.  But SQL Server probably won't use any index on your current query.